# Missing $ inserted when use \texttt

Tags: math-mode, errors, text, typewriter, missing

I have this simple code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

% amsmath package, useful for mathematical formulas
\usepackage{amsmath}
% amssymb package, useful for mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{changepage}
% graphicx package, useful for including eps and pdf graphics
% include graphics with the command \includegraphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

% cite package, to clean up citations in the main text. Do not remove.
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{color}

% Use doublespacing - comment out for single spacing
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing

% Text layout
\topmargin 0.0cm
\oddsidemargin 0.5cm
\evensidemargin 0.5cm
\textwidth 16cm
\textheight 21cm

% Bold the 'Figure #' in the caption and separate it with a period
% Captions will be left justified

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
% Allow long tables to be split over multiple pages
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{TEST}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Equations}

\noindent Example Equation
\begin{equation}
E_x= 1-e^{-k_{time}t}
\end{equation}

...

\texttt{E_x}

\end{document}
```

I receive "Missing $ inserted" on the `\texttt{E_x}`, but I know that `\texttt{}` function is used to produce a text-mode of what it has inside the {}. What am I wrong?

Comment: I think the underscore has to be inside math mode. \texttt is just for looks (text formatting) not for content modification (i.e. like $$). If you're looking to print "E_x" like that without transforming it you want the verbose environment or \verb!E_x! .

Comment: you need `\_` to get a _ in text

Comment: unrelated but use `k_{\mathrm{time}}` the version you have will space `t i m e` like a product of variables not a word.

Comment: Ty for the answers: I want to display "E_x", not the mathematical form "Ex" and in the https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/texttt.htm I have supposed that texttt will be the correct function tu use. To be onest, I receive an error with "\texttt{\alpha}" too, so the problem is not the underscore, but the use of mathematical form in the \texttt, but, if I will understand correctly, \texttt function is used to display in textual form what it has inside the {}. I need to display the name of a matlab variable in textual form (this is my final purpose). Ty

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\texttt{E\textsubscript{\_n}}
```

Comment: With \texttt{E\textsubscript{n}}, I have no errors, but I don't want in display "En" but "E_n", because in the original text I want to display the name of the variable that I have implemented in matlab (in the matlab lenguage). Any other suggestion? Ty

Comment: add a \ in front of the underscore in the line of code

Comment: This solution works well, Ty!